# Attempting to Optimize Python loops with tons of conditionals

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, optimization, nested-loops

I am working on adapting some C code to Python. In general, I am very inexperienced with C, and the code was written in C90, and when compiled on a local machine will not provide accurate results.

Because of this, I wanted to "future-proof" the program that I am using. While I have a good grasp on what the program does, it runs extraordinarily slow compared to its C equivalent. I would like to see if I can optimize this code without having to add Cython to the mix.

To give an idea of what this code is doing. It begins at a starting point, surrounded by a small 5x5x5 cube. Within the cube, travel times to the central point at each cell are calculated (denoted as time0[index]). From there, the cube expands by 1 cell in each dimension, until calculating travel times for a predefined area (400x400x53 in my case).

The problem with this is that calculating the travel time relies on the neighbouring cells, calculated in previous steps in a for loop (which can be up to 160000 iterations per cell expansion). Each wall of the cube is expanded upon by a for loop, which each contain 49 if statements. This totals 294 if statements for all 6 loops, which run for every expansion of the dimensions of the cube.

To make a long story short, there are a LOT of if statements, being executed here. I have included a sample of the code below for the expanding top portion of the cube. I would definitely appreciate some advice here, since this code is beyond any previous project that I have taken on.

```
        if dz1 > 0:
            ii = 0
            for j in range(y1+1,y2):
                for i in range(x1+1,x2):
                    sort.time[ii] = T0[i,j,z1+1]
                    sort.i1[ii] = i
                    sort.i2[ii] = j
                    ii += 1
                    print(j,i)
            sort_index = np.argsort(sort.time[0:ii])
            sort.time[0:ii] = sort.time[sort_index]
            sort.i1[0:ii] = sort.i1[sort_index]
            sort.i2[0:ii] = sort.i2[sort_index]
            for i in range(0,ii):
                X1 = int(sort.i1[i])
                X2 = int(sort.i2[i])
                index = int(z1*nxy + X2*nx + X1)
                lasti = int((z1+1)*nxy + X2*nx + X1)
                fhead = 0
                guess = time0[index]
                if time0[index+1] < 1.e9 and time0[index+nx+1] < 1.e9 and time0[index+nx] < 1.e9 and X2 < ny-1 and X1 < nx-1:
                    attempt = fdh3d(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2+1,z1+1],T0[X1,X2+1,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2,z1],T0[X1+1,X2+1,z1],T0[X1,X2+1,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1+1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1+1,X2+1,z1+1],S0[X1,X2+1,z1+1],S0[X1+1,X2,z1],S0[X1+1,X2+1,z1],S0[X1,X2+1,z1])
                    if attempt < guess:
                        guess = attempt
                if time0[index-1] < 1.e9 and time0[index+nx-1] < 1.e9 and time0[index+nx] < 1.e9 and X2<ny-1  and X1>0:
                    attempt = fdh3d(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1-1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1-1,X2+1,z1+1],T0[X1,X2+1,z1+1],T0[X1-1,X2,z1],T0[X1-1,X2+1,z1],T0[X1,X2+1,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1-1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1-1,X2+1,z1+1],S0[X1,X2+1,z1+1],S0[X1-1,X2,z1],S0[X1-1,X2+1,z1],S0[X1,X2+1,z1])
                    if attempt<guess:
                        guess = attempt
                if time0[index+1] < 1.e9 and time0[index-nx+1] < 1.e9 and time0[index-nx] < 1.e9 and X2>0  and X1<nx-1:
                    attempt = fdh3d(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2-1,z1+1],T0[X1,X2-1,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2,z1],T0[X1+1,X2-1,z1],T0[X1,X2-1,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1+1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1+1,X2-1,z1+1],S0[X1,X2-1,z1+1],S0[X1+1,X2,z1  ],S0[X1+1,X2-1,z1],S0[X1,X2-1,z1])
                    if attempt<guess: 
                        guess = attempt
                if time0[index-1] < 1.e9 and time0[index-nx-1] < 1.e9 and time0[index-nx] < 1.e9 and X2>0  and X1>0:
                    attempt = fdh3d(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1-1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1-1,X2-1,z1+1],T0[X1,X2-1,z1+1],T0[X1-1,X2,z1  ],T0[X1-1,X2-1,z1],T0[X1,X2-1,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1-1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1-1,X2-1,z1+1],S0[X1,X2-1,z1+1],S0[X1-1,X2,z1  ],S0[X1-1,X2-1,z1],S0[X1,X2-1,z1])
                    if attempt<guess: 
                        guess = attempt
                if guess > 1.0e9:
                    if time0[index+1] < 1.e9 and X1<nx-1 and X2>y1+1 and X2<y2-1:
                        attempt = fdhne(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2,z1],T0[X1+1,X2-1,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2+1,z1+1], S0[X1,X2,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1+1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1+1,X2,z1] )
                        if attempt<guess:
                            guess = attempt
                    if time0[index-1] < 1.e9 and X1>0 and X2>y1+1 and X2<y2-1:
                        attempt = fdhne(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1-1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1-1,X2,z1],T0[X1-1,X2-1,z1+1],T0[X1-1,X2+1,z1+1], S0[X1,X2,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1-1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1-1,X2,z1] )
                        if attempt<guess:
                            guess = attempt
                    if time0[index+nx] < 1.e9 and X2<ny-1 and X1>x1+1 and X1<x2-1:
                        attempt = fdhne(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1,X2+1,z1+1],T0[X1,X2+1,z1],T0[X1-1,X2+1,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2+1,z1+1], S0[X1,X2,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1,X2+1,z1+1],S0[X1,X2+1,z1] )
                        if attempt<guess:
                            guess = attempt
                    if time0[index-nx] < 1.e9 and X2>0 and X1>x1+1 and X1<x2-1:
                        attempt = fdhne(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1,X2-1,z1+1],T0[X1,X2-1,z1],T0[X1-1,X2-1,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2-1,z1+1], S0[X1,X2,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1,X2-1,z1+1],S0[X1,X2-1,z1])
                        if attempt<guess: 
                            guess = attempt
                if time0[index+1] < 1.e9 and X1<nx-1:
                    attempt = fdh2d(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1], S0[X1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1+1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1+1,X2,z1])
                    if attempt<guess:
                        guess = attempt
                if time0[index-1] < 1.e9 and X1>0:
                    attempt = fdh2d(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1-1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1-1,X2,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1], S0[X1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1-1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1-1,X2,z1])
                    if attempt<guess:
                        guess = attempt
                if time0[index+nx] < 1.e9 and X2<ny-1:
                    attempt = fdh2d(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1,X2+1,z1+1],T0[X1,X2+1,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1], S0[X1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1,X2+1,z1+1],S0[X1,X2+1,z1])
                    if attempt<guess:
                        guess = attempt
                if time0[index-nx] < 1.e9 and X2>0:
                    attempt = fdh2d(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1,X2-1,z1+1],T0[X1,X2-1,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1], S0[X1,X2,z1+1],S0[X1,X2-1,z1+1],S0[X1,X2-1,z1])
                    if attempt<guess:
                        guess = attempt
                if time0[index+1] < 1.e9 and time0[index+nx+1] < 1.e9 and time0[index+nx] < 1.e9 and X2<ny-1  and X1<nx-1:
                    attempt = fdh2d(T0[X1+1,X2,z1],T0[X1+1,X2+1,z1],T0[X1,X2+1,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1], S0[X1+1,X2,z1],S0[X1+1,X2+1,z1],S0[X1,X2+1,z1])
                    if attempt<guess:
                        fhead=(guess-attempt)/slow0[index]
                        guess=attempt
                if time0[index+1] < 1.e9 and time0[index-nx+1] < 1.e9 and time0[index-nx] < 1.e9 and X2>0  and X1<nx-1:
                    attempt = fdh2d(T0[X1+1,X2,z1],T0[X1+1,X2-1,z1],T0[X1,X2-1,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1], S0[X1+1,X2,z1],S0[X1+1,X2-1,z1],S0[X1,X2-1,z1])
                    if attempt<guess:
                        fhead=(guess-attempt)/slow0[index]
                        guess=attempt
                if time0[index-1] < 1.e9 and time0[index+nx-1] < 1.e9 and time0[index+nx] < 1.e9 and X2<ny-1  and X1>0:
                    attempt = fdh2d(T0[X1-1,X2,z1],T0[X1-1,X2+1,z1],T0[X1,X2+1,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1],S0[X1-1,X2,z1],S0[X1-1,X2+1,z1],S0[X1,X2+1,z1])
                    if attempt<guess:
                        fhead=(guess-attempt)/slow0[index]
                        guess=attempt
                if time0[index-1] < 1.e9 and time0[index-nx-1] < 1.e9 and time0[index-nx] < 1.e9 and X2>0  and X1>0:
                    attempt = fdh2d(T0[X1-1,X2,z1],T0[X1-1,X2-1,z1],T0[X1,X2-1,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1],S0[X1-1,X2,z1],S0[X1-1,X2-1,z1],S0[X1,X2-1,z1])
                    if attempt<guess:
                        fhead=(guess-attempt)/slow0[index]
                        guess=attempt
                if guess > 1.0e9:
                    if X1>x1+1 and X1<x2-1 and X2>y1+1 and X2<y2-1:
                        attempt = fdhnf(T0[X1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1+1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1,X2+1,z1+1],T0[X1-1,X2,z1+1],T0[X1,X2-1,z1+1],S0[X1,X2,z1],S0[X1,X2,z1+1] )
                        if attempt<guess:
                            guess = attempt
                attempt = T0[X1,X2,z1+1] + .5*(S0[X1,X2,z1]+S0[X1,X2,z1+1])
                if attempt<guess:
                    guess = attempt
                if time0[index+1]<1.e9 and X1<nx-1:
                    attempt = T0[X1+1,X2,z1] + .5*(S0[X1,X2,z1]+S0[X1+1,X2,z1])
                    if attempt<guess:
                        fhead=(guess-attempt)/slow0[index]
                        guess=attempt
                if time0[index-1]<1.e9 and X1>0:
                    attempt = T0[X1-1,X2,z1] + .5*(S0[X1,X2,z1]+S0[X1-1,X2,z1])
                    if attempt<guess:
                        fhead=(guess-attempt)/slow0[index]
                        guess=attempt
                if time0[index+nx]<1.e9 and X2<ny-1:
                    attempt = T0[X1,X2+1,z1] + .5*(S0[X1,X2,z1]+S0[X1,X2+1,z1])
                    if attempt<guess:
                        fhead=(guess-attempt)/slow0[index]
                        guess=attempt
                if time0[index-nx]<1.e9 and X2>0:
                    attempt = T0[X1,X2-1,z1] + .5*(S0[X1,X2,z1]+S0[X1,X2-1,z1]);
                    if attempt<guess:
                        fhead=(guess-attempt)/slow0[index]
                        guess=attempt
                if guess < time0[index]:
                    time0[index] = guess
                    T0[X1,X2,z1] = guess
                    if fhead > headtest:
                        headw[5]+=1
            if z1 == 0:
                dz1 = 0
            z1-=1
```

I did also attempt to speed up the code by reducing the size of the for loops, however this actually slowed down the code! Here is an example of what I did:

```
        if dz1 > 0:
            ii = 0
            sort.time = np.ndarray.flatten(T0[x1+1:x2,y1+1:y2,z1+1])
            sort.i1 = np.array([(i) for i, j in product(range(x1+1,x2), range(y1+1,y2))])
            sort.i2 = np.array([(j) for i, j in product(range(x1+1,x2), range(y1+1,y2))])
            ii = sort.time.size
            sort_index = np.argsort(sort.time)
            sort.time = sort.time[sort_index]
            sort.i1 = sort.i1[sort_index]
            sort.i2 = sort.i2[sort_index]
            for X1,X2 in zip(sort.i1,sort.i2):
                 index = z1*nxy + X2*nx + X1
```

Comment: I have discovered that using the Numba module for a number of the smaller functions invoked in this block of the code has really helped to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

That is one ugly lump of code.  Pretty incomprehensible.  Only thing that comes to mind is transforming your if-if-if structure into if-elif-elif structure which is the proper way to do it if you have mutually exclusive cases.  That will avoid some math and speed things up a bit, but honestly, this needs re-consideration from the ground up.

Comment: From what I can tell, the if statements are all mutually exclusive, so else if statements probably won't be possible. The "attempt" variable is calculated under slightly different conditions and then tested against the previous "attempt", which is assigned the "guess" variable. If the current "attempt" is less than the "guess", it is assigned as the new "guess".